# How to align my Bootstrap html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

When I change the  to  at at line one. I get the following alignment.

I have got only the input boxes aligned "center" but not the labels. Sorry, I couldn't upload the screenshot here.

I have tried also with all the next nested div until form tag. But there is no use.

Can anybody help to align my form?

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>

            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Ajouter un employé</legend>

            <!-- Select Basic -->
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic">Titre</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-small">
                        <option>M.</option>
                        <option>Mme.</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="prenom">Prénom</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="prenom" name="prenom" type="text" placeholder="Prénom" class="input-xlarge" required="">

                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

I have tried also for each div of label and input tags. But it's not getting aligned center. I am totally stuck. Can anybody please pay attention to my post?

Comment: I thought the classes were `form-group`, `form-control` instead of `control-group` and `controls` respectively, at least that's what I use....

Comment: @CallumLinington that's for Bootstrap 3, but it looks like Devarajan is using Bootstrap 2.3.2, which used `control` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to center.
 
Are you trying to just center the form? If so, put the form in a `container-fluid`, a `row-fluid` and a div with something like `span8 offset2`. 

Are you trying to have one column of labels and one column of inputs, and have the space between them centered horizontally? Are you trying to make everything have text-alignment be center? Let us know.

Comment: @CallumLinington : Small change :  I am using bootstrap 2.3.1

Comment: @seanmhanson : As i said, i couldn't upload an image here.  i tried to center the form first. But the result was only "All the input field got centered". It was looking bizzare that my labels got aligned left. So i did undo it as like it was. And i have used `style="margin: 0.5% 0 0 35%;"`

Comment: You didn't close the `fieldset` before `</form>` !!

Comment: You should use `</fieldset>` instead of `<fieldset>` ...

Comment: I've made [this Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/nGfd7YeOUk) using your code. Are you getting the same results as in the Bootply?

Comment: exactly the same. But it's not aligned center. I have tried within all the tag by adding this attribute value  `"text-center"` . But it doesn't work. My form would have missed the container. I could add it. But it's not aligned center.

Comment: possible duplicate of [center horizontal-form twitter bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982957/center-horizontal-form-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: It's the same result i have got. Centralised, But there was big gap between the labels and input fields after i have used body{ text-align:center }.

Comment: I was needed something like this http://www.bootply.com/hmYGC6GVU4